# Is there restriction in Apigee tool from cloud to customize the portal page?

Tags: apigee

Is there any restriction in Apigee tool from Cloud to customize the portal page ?

We are looking for developer portal like http://developer.nytimes.com/

Do we need actual APigee tool or Apigee free version from cloud support us to customize the page.

Answer (score 0):

Apigee no longer offers a free option for developer portal.  There are no restrictions on the paid version.

My understanding is that if you still have the free version of the dev portal that it is fully customizable to the extent that you can install and activate drupal modules and completely customize the CSS. But anything that would require file system access is not allowed. You also would not be able to get a custom domain name like developer.yourcompany.com

However, as it's not being offered anymore (and was only offered briefly) your free account may also go away

Comment: I have a free version of developer community. URL is http://dev-damuorgn.devportal.apigee.com/blog

Comment: Please let me know whether there is a restrction in free version. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there any documentation or URL to customize the developer portal like adding menus, changing color and how to activate drupai modules.

Comment: Basically, we are looking developer portal like this website. PLease let me know your thoughts. http://developer.nytimes.com/